# Alternative ways to write a file in Java

Tags: java, file-io

I have next function:

```
static void write()
{
    try {
         File file = new File ("flip.out");
         BufferedWriter out = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(file));
         out.write(sMax);
         System.out.println(sMax);//This command it works
         out.close();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

The problem is that my program doesn't write anything in my file.

Comment: where does that sMax come from?

Comment: sMax is a member of the class. When I call System.out.println(sMax) it is showed in the console

Comment: @Kugathasan Abimaran No exceptions!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to flush the stream in order for what's in the memory to get written to the drive.  What you wrote to BufferedWriter is sitting in a byte array waiting for the rest of it to be filled up before actually writing it to the disk.  This helps with performance, but means you have to flush the stream in case you don't fill up that buffer.  Here is how you do that:

```
static void write() throws IOException {
    BufferedWriter out = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter("flip.out"));
    try {
        out.write(sMax);
        out.flush();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        // probably could ditch this and 
        // just the exception bubble up and 
        // handle it higher up.
        e.printStackTrace(); 
    } finally {
        out.close();
    }
}
```

So if it makes it to the flush() we know we wrote everything to the stream we wanted.  However, if we ever get an exception we make sure we close the stream regardless of success or exception.  And finally our stream is outside the try statement because the only exception ever thrown by Writers/OutputStreams during construction is FileNotFoundException which means the file never got opened in the first place so we don't have to close it.

Answer (score 1):

Few things to rectify -

Why create two different instances of File object

```
File file = new File ("flip.out");
BufferedWriter out = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter("flip.out"));
```

All you need to do is

```
File file = new File ("flip.out");
BufferedWriter out = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriterfile(file ) ));
```

Next put your close call in `finally statement` rather than try block. Why? Because of IOException occurs resource will not be closed and if resource do not get closed your changes may not be reflected in the file.

Next it is a good programming practice not to catch `Runtime exceptions`. So do not use `Exception` as a ploymorphic type to catch your exception. Use whatever is being thrown like IOException in your case.

Now there might be various reasons why noting is being written in the file. As you are not getting and Exception one of the reason why this might be happening because your static function is not getting called or the string/object `sMax`(whatever that is) is empty.

Also the file(if not already present) will be created in the current directory. So if there are multiple instance is your code where your are creating files with same name then make sure you are checking the right one.

Answer (score 0):

can you call `out.flush()` before closing.
that will make sure any content in buffer is written to file immediately.